# How to display checkbox results according to my database model?

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

I have two variables, one stores the chexboxes and the other stores the values checked, I found a problem to display the checkboxes and their values (checked, not checked) from the controller to the view.
I have this code on the controller

```
$scope.infoParticipant = functionThatGetsParticipants();
           for (var i = 0; i < $scope.infoParticipant.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.infoParticipant[i].ch_type == 'checkbox_multiple') {
                            var optionsString = $scope.infoParticipant[i].cf_multiple_optionsList;
                            $scope.infoParticipant[i].optionsTab = optionsString.split(";");
                            var optionsSelected = $scope.infoParticipant[i].v_value.split(";");
                    }
}
```

In the precedent code these should be the values

```
optionsString = "ch1;ch2;ch3";
$scope.infoParticipant[i].v_value = "ch1;ch2";
```

According to this the checkboxes :ch1 and ch2 will be checked on the next view :

```
      <div ng-show="l.ch_type=='checkbox_multiple'">
            <label >My checkboxes</span></label>

            <div class="row" ng-repeat="k in l.optionsTab">

            <div class=" col-md-2 modal_style_input">{{k}} </div> 
            <div class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" name="option" class="md-input" id="option {{k}}"  class="wizard-icheck" value="{{k}}" icheck ng-model="" /></div>
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

My question is how to modify my controller and what to put on ng-model to have my correct chexboxes checked?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, one solution would be to use [ngCheck](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) directive in your check boxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="option {{k}}" value="{{k}}" ng-check="isOptionAvailable({{k}})" /></div>
```

And the isOptionAvailable(opt) is a javascript function that you add to the scope which returns true when k is present in $scope.infoParticipant[i].v_value.

EDIT: To answer your last comment, I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uJ6SjodhWWfc2crmLjfT?p=preview) showing how it works

Comment: Thanks for you response Jean-Nicolas, the problem is that $scope.infoParticipant[i].v_value is declared under the function $scope.getParticipant() and I am obliged to declare isOptionAvailable under this function to compare with $scope.infoParticipant[i].optionsTab, but $scope.getParticipant is executed only one time to display the form, so isOptionAvailable is not accessible, how to correct that ?